# Teradatasql Python: Unable to pass Named Parameters into script

Tags: python, parameters, teradata

I'm using the teradatasql python package and i'm unable to find any documentation on how to pass named parameters into the cursor.execute()

for example:
select ?month_end_dt , ?month_begin_dt

I'd like to be able to pass variables from a dictionary into the named parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/#CursorMethods for documentation of the execute() method!

Answer (score 0):

The `teradatasql` package does not support named parameters. It only supports unnamed question-mark parameter markers.